# Is there way to ignore Ids generated to Binding class

Tags: android-viewbinding

When using viewBinding with ConstraintLayout, maybe a lot of Ids will be create to help describe the view relationship, but will never used in Kotlin/Java.

I just found two useful tools attribute

1. `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` used to prevent whole layout generated in Binding, but not for single Id.
2. `tools:viewBindingType="TextView"` used for changing the Type generated in Binding.

So is there any way to ignore Id(s)? I don't want to expose them to pollute the Kotlin/Java.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to ignore view binding generation on view by view basis. If you use Proguard the unused ViewBinding IDs will be removed from the final APK.